# Installing a script on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was trying to install this carousel, but I have no idea how.
In its documentation it says "Load the required stylesheet and JS" and give me this code:

```
import 'owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css';
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'imports?jQuery=jquery!owl.carousel';
```

But I have no idea where and how to do it, the full documentation is here: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/started-installation.html

I'm just asking for someone to teach me how to do it, I really need to use this thing in my code and I have no idea how so far.

```css
.div-aperto-maos {
 
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
 padding: 0%;
 
 
 }

.aperto-maos {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.areas-de-atuacao {
   background-color: rgba(15,105,75,1.00);
 text-align: center;
 color: white;

 
}

.areas-de-atuacao hr {
 border-width: 5px;
 border-color: white;
 width: 70px;
 padding-top: 5%;
}

.areas-de-atuacao h2 {
 font-size: 50px;
 padding-top: 5%;
}


.cartoes-container {
 
 height: 2350px;
 background-color: rgba(15,105,75,1.00);
}

.cartoes-atuacao {
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-top: 1%;
 border-radius: 15px;
 max-height: inherit;
 text-align: center;
 height: 750px;
 background-color: white;
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #FFFFFF 80%, #D3D3D3 00%);
}

.cartoes-atuacao h2 {
 color: rgba(15,105,75,1.00);
 font-size: 45px;
}

.cartoes-atuacao h3 {
 
 font-weight: 300;
 color: grey;
 margin-top: 40px;
 font-size: 34px;

}

.img-card {
 border: solid;
 border-width: 0.1px;
 border-radius: 100%;
 margin-top: 10%;
}




.artigos-e-noticias {
   background-color: white;
 text-align: center;
 color: white;

 
}

.artigos-e-noticias hr {
 border-width: 5px;
 border-color: rgba(15,105,75,1.00);
 width: 70px;
 padding-top: 5%;
}

.artigos-e-noticias h2 {
 color: black;
 font-size: 50px;
 padding-top: 5%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">



<link rel="stylesheet" href="owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="owlcarousel/owl.theme.default.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>





import 'owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css';
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'imports?jQuery=jquery!owl.carousel';
 

 




<link href="Home.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>

<section id="conte-equiepe">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-12 div-aperto-maos">
  
  <img class="img-fluid aperto-maos" src="Imagens/conte-com-uma-equipe.png">
  
  </div>
  
  </div>
  
  </div>
  
  
   
 
 
 
 
</section>

<section>
 
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4 areas-de-atuacao">
   
    
    
    
    
   </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 areas-de-atuacao">
   
    
    <h2> Áreas de Atuação </h2>
    <hr>
    
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 areas-de-atuacao">
   
    
    
    
    
   </div>
  </div> 
 </div>
 
  
   
  
   
   
   
 
 
 
</section>

<section>
 <div class="container-fluid cartoes-container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-3 cartoes-atuacao">
    
    <img class="img-fluid img-card" src="Imagens/card1.png">
    <h2> Direito Civil</h2>
    <h3> Assessoria preventiva,
consultiva e contenciosa
relacionadas a obrigações e
contratos, execuções
judiciais, responsabilidade
civil, indenizações e demais
conflitos de natureza civil.</h3>
    
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 cartoes-atuacao">
    
    <img class="img-fluid img-card" src="Imagens/card1.png">
    <h2> Direito Civil</h2>
    <h3> Assessoria preventiva,
consultiva e contenciosa
relacionadas a obrigações e
contratos, execuções
judiciais, responsabilidade
civil, indenizações e demais
conflitos de natureza civil.</h3>
    
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 cartoes-atuacao">
    
    <img class="img-fluid img-card" src="Imagens/card1.png">
    <h2> Direito Civil</h2>
    <h3> Assessoria preventiva,
consultiva e contenciosa
relacionadas a obrigações e
contratos, execuções
judiciais, responsabilidade
civil, indenizações e demais
conflitos de natureza civil.</h3>
    
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 cartoes-atuacao">
    
    <img class="img-fluid img-card" src="Imagens/card1.png">
    <h2> Direito Civil</h2>
    <h3> Assessoria preventiva,
consultiva e contenciosa
relacionadas a obrigações e
contratos, execuções
judiciais, responsabilidade
civil, indenizações e demais
conflitos de natureza civil.</h3>
    
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 cartoes-atuacao">
    
    <img class="img-fluid img-card" src="Imagens/card1.png">
    <h2> Direito Civil</h2>
    <h3> Assessoria preventiva,
consultiva e contenciosa
relacionadas a obrigações e
contratos, execuções
judiciais, responsabilidade
civil, indenizações e demais
conflitos de natureza civil.</h3>
    
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 cartoes-atuacao">
    
    <img class="img-fluid img-card" src="Imagens/card1.png">
    <h2> Direito Civil</h2>
    <h3> Assessoria preventiva,
consultiva e contenciosa
relacionadas a obrigações e
contratos, execuções
judiciais, responsabilidade
civil, indenizações e demais
conflitos de natureza civil.</h3>
    
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 cartoes-atuacao">
    
    <img class="img-fluid img-card" src="Imagens/card1.png">
    <h2> Direito Civil</h2>
    <h3> Assessoria preventiva,
consultiva e contenciosa
relacionadas a obrigações e
contratos, execuções
judiciais, responsabilidade
civil, indenizações e demais
conflitos de natureza civil.</h3>
    
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 cartoes-atuacao">
    
    <img class="img-fluid img-card" src="Imagens/card1.png">
    <h2> Direito Civil</h2>
    <h3> Assessoria preventiva,
consultiva e contenciosa
relacionadas a obrigações e
contratos, execuções
judiciais, responsabilidade
civil, indenizações e demais
conflitos de natureza civil.</h3>
    
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 cartoes-atuacao">
    
    <img class="img-fluid img-card" src="Imagens/card1.png">
    <h2> Direito Civil</h2>
    <h3> Assessoria preventiva,
consultiva e contenciosa
relacionadas a obrigações e
contratos, execuções
judiciais, responsabilidade
civil, indenizações e demais
conflitos de natureza civil.</h3>
    
   </div>
   
  </div>
 </div>
 
 
 
 
</section>
 
<section>
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4 artigos-e-noticias">
   
    
    
    
    
   </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 artigos-e-noticias">
   
    
    <h2> Ártigos / Notícias </h2>
    <hr>
    
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 artigos-e-noticias">
   
    
    
    
    
   </div>
  </div> 
 </div>
</section>

 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel();
});</script>

<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div> <img src="Imagens/conta.png"> </div>
  <div> <img src="Imagens/conta.png"> </div>
  <div> <img src="Imagens/conta.png"> </div>
  <div> <img src="Imagens/conta.png"> </div>
  <div> <img src="Imagens/conta.png"> </div>
  <div> <img src="Imagens/conta.png"></div>
  <div> <img src="Imagens/conta.png"> </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>

<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of noise in your code, here is a working example.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.theme.min.css">


<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div> <img src="https://c402277.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/photos/13100/images/featured_story/BIC_128.png?1485963152"> </div>
  <div> <img src="https://c402277.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/photos/13100/images/featured_story/BIC_128.png?1485963152"> </div>
  <div> <img src="https://c402277.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/photos/13100/images/featured_story/BIC_128.png?1485963152"> </div>
  <div> <img src="https://c402277.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/photos/13100/images/featured_story/BIC_128.png?1485963152"> </div>
  <div> <img src="https://c402277.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/photos/13100/images/featured_story/BIC_128.png?1485963152"> </div>
</div>

<script>
  function main() {
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel();
  }
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-k2WSCIexGzOj3Euiig+TlR8gA0EmPjuc79OEeY5L45g=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js" onload="main()"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `import` with `Webpack/Babel`.

If you just want to use the code, you can open this file and copy it all in your code.

Note the order of the code.

Answer (score 0):

https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/started-installation.html

The files you need is in the folder **OwlCarousel2-2.2.1\dist** and **OwlCarousel2-2.2.1\dist\assets**

Create a **owlcarousel** in your project and put the files **owl.theme.default.min.css, owl.carousel.min.css and owl.carousel.min.js** there

Remember to download jQuery https://jquery.com/download/ and put **jquery.min.js** in your root folder

Follow install instructions in order and it should work

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be better if you checkout [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you